# How to display data in a Sheet from another Google Sheet that meets certain criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I've got a Google Form that gathers data into a Google Sheet #1 (say, requests from employees to work on certain days).
My goal is to make a pretty-print list of people who requested to work this week Saturday and Sunday.
Looks like I need to have the data from sheet #1 appear at sheet #2 if it meets certain criteria - all the employee names who's working day from sheet #1 equals to this Saturday.

How can I automatically have in sheet #2 certain data from sheet #1 that meets a criteria?
How can I describe the criteria 'smth equals to this Saturday and Sunday'?
How can I create an output Google Form from sheet #2 formatted nicely ready to print?

Comment: Submitters fill request, providing their names, date when to work, and type of work planned to do. Requests automatically go to the sheet #1. A manager wants all the employees' names who requested to work on weekends to appear in sheet #2 to be quickly printed.

Comment: I tried a query similar to that, but for some reason whatever the `where` condition is, I always obtain only the first row with column headers and no actual data. My query was: `=(QUERY(Responses!$A:$E,ʺselect C,D,E where dayofweek(B)=1ʺ))`

Comment: Got that working. Seems that the week starts on Sunday. However, using `dayOfWeek()` doesn't limit the day to _this_ weekend, just any weekend. How to narrow the criteria to this weekend?

Comment: Well, I'll figure out the condition using it like 'day #1 or #7 after today but less than 6 days ahead'. I'm now wandering about the formatting of the output for printing. I s there a way to make a 'consolidated report' on a sheet #2 using kind of a template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try:

```
=query(Responses!A:E,"Select C,D,E where B < date '"&text(today()+6,"yyyy-MM-dd")&"' and (dayOfWeek(B) = 1 or dayOfWeek(B) = 7)")
```